# How to Use Checkbox in Custom Option Page Using The Setting API

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, settings-api

Can you please let me know how I can add a checkbox to Setting API in creating Custom Options Page? I am using the following code to add a txt box which is working perfectly but I am totally confused how to add chechbox to the setting API and options. I just tried ti update the input type to checkbox but I am not sure what to put in Value besides when I save the form the check box still appears unchecked!

```
 add_settings_field('the_option_label',
                    'Display Paragraph:',
                     array($this,'the_option_label_setting'),
                     __FILE__,
                     'hte_main_section');

 public function the_option_label_setting()
    {
       echo "<input name='My_Theme_Options[the_option_label]' type='text' value='{$this->options['the_option_label']}'/>";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Its simple to read and understand. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/creating-custom-options-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at: [The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API (Part 8: Validation, Sanitisation, and Input II)](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-8-validation-sanitisation-and-input-ii/):

```
add_settings_field(  
    'Checkbox Element',  
    'Checkbox Element',  
    'sandbox_checkbox_element_callback',  
    'sandbox_theme_input_examples',  
    'input_examples_section'  
);

function sandbox_checkbox_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_example" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[checkbox_example]" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options['checkbox_example'], false ) . '/>';
    $html .= '<label for="checkbox_example">This is an example of a checkbox</label>';

    echo $html;

}
```

EDIT: Check box fields do not use the `value` attribute to determine if the box is checked. They use a `checked` attribute. The `$html` line above has been edited using the code from later in the article referenced above. Read the articles for details.

Comment: Hi Till Thanks for your comment I tried your hint and the code from the link but I am still having some issues here! The problem is when I checked the checkbox and save the options the new page is still unchecked! I mean it is not reading the data from the Options! Can you please let me know how to do this ? I know in Text box we can use the value='{$this->options['the_option_label']} but how about the checkbox?

Comment: Edited [Till](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26399/till)'s answer with corrected code from the article.

Comment: Maybe it's better if we check the option is set like `checked( 1, $options['checkbox_example'] ?? '', false )`. Just in case we don't want an error or a warning message for that.